# URL with Hierarchical Taxonomies and same slug for all terms and sub-terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, register-taxonomy

I have a **'house'** cpt and a **'locations'** hierarchical custom taxonomy.
Permalinks are set to

```
/%category%/%postname%
```

The terms in the hierarchical taxonomy are like:

**usa >> new-york**

**germany >> berlin**

The code in my functions.php:

```
// Register Taxonomy locations
function register_taxonomy_locations() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Locations', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'genesis' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Location', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'genesis' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Locations', 'genesis' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All Locations', 'genesis' ),
    'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Location', 'genesis' ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Location:', 'genesis' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Location Name', 'genesis' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Location', 'genesis' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Location', 'genesis' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update Location', 'genesis' ),
    'view_item'                  => __( 'View Location', 'genesis' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Locations with commas', 'genesis' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove Locations', 'genesis' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'genesis' ),
    'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Locations', 'genesis' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Search Locations', 'genesis' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'genesis' ),
    'no_terms'                   => __( 'No Locations', 'genesis' ),
    'items_list'                 => __( 'Locations list', 'genesis' ),
    'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Locations list navigation', 'genesis' ),
);
$rewrite = array(
    'slug'                       => 'houses',
    'with_front'                 => true,
    'hierarchical'               => false,
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    'query_var'                  => true,
    'rewrite'                    => $rewrite,
);
register_taxonomy( 'locations', array( 'house' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'register_taxonomy_locations', 0 );

// Register CPT House
function register_cpt_house() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x( 'Houses', 'Post Type General Name', 'genesis' ),
    'singular_name'         => _x( 'House', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'genesis' ),
    'menu_name'             => __( 'House', 'genesis' ),
    'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Houses', 'genesis' ),
    'archives'              => __( 'House Archives', 'genesis' ),
    'attributes'            => __( 'House Attributes', 'genesis' ),
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent House:', 'genesis' ),
    'all_items'             => __( 'All Houses', 'genesis' ),
    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New House', 'genesis' ),
    'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'genesis' ),
    'new_item'              => __( 'New House', 'genesis' ),
    'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit House', 'genesis' ),
    'update_item'           => __( 'Update House', 'genesis' ),
    'view_item'             => __( 'View House', 'genesis' ),
    'view_items'            => __( 'View Houses', 'genesis' ),
    'search_items'          => __( 'Search House', 'genesis' ),
    'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'genesis' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'genesis' ),
    'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'genesis' ),
    'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'genesis' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'genesis' ),
    'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'genesis' ),
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this House', 'genesis' ),
    'items_list'            => __( 'Houses list', 'genesis' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Houses list navigation', 'genesis' ),
    'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter Houses list', 'genesis' ),
);
$rewrite = array(
    'slug'                  => 'house',
    'with_front'            => true,
    'pages'                 => true,
    'feeds'                 => true,
);
$args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'House', 'genesis' ),
    'description'           => __( 'CPT House', 'genesis' ),
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', ),
    'taxonomies'            => array( 'locations' ),
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-admin-home',
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'rewrite'               => $rewrite,
    'capability_type'       => 'post',
    'query_var'             => true,
    'permalink_epmask'      => EP_PERMALINK,
    'show_in_rest'          => false,
);

register_post_type( 'house', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_house', 0 );

// Add Archive Settings option to house CPT
add_post_type_support( 'house', 'genesis-cpt-archives-settings' );
```

So, for a single house post URL is https://website.com/house/house-1, for a parent term page URL should be https://website.com/houses/usa and for a sub-term page should be https://website.com/houses/new-york

When viewing any house, the URL is https://website.com/house/house-1, https://website.com/house/house-2, etc, which is correct.

When viewing a parent term page, like https://website.com/houses/usa or https://website.com/houses/germany, it shows the houses in those parent terms, which is correct.

**But when viewing a sub-term page, like https://website.com/houses/new-york or https://website.com/houses/berlin, it's a 404. I can't find why.**

Of course, https://website.com/houses/usa/new-york or https://website.com/usa/new-york don't work either, but I don't want those.

If, instead of writting the code myself in **functions.php**, I use any plugin such as Types or Custom Post Type UI with the same requirements, I can see any of the taxonomy pages with no problems at all.

I'm sure this has to be a very simple issue, but I can't see it.

Thanks in advance

** **UPDATED** **

The code above works well when there's only one taxonomy for one cpt.
The issue appears when you add another taxonomy with the same code as above (obviously changing to the new taxonomy name).
For the sake of brevity, I described the issue with one taxonomy. Sorry for that, I should have specified that there are more taxonomies involved.
With every taxonomy, I need to have the same slug for every term, like:

```
https://website.com/houses/term-of-taxonomy-A/
https://website.com/houses/sub-term-of-taxonomy-A/
https://website.com/houses/term-of-taxonomy-B/
https://website.com/houses/sub-term-of-taxonomy-B/
```

Comment: Your code works as expected for me, child terms are not 404s. Are you sure those terms are assigned to posts?

Comment: Sorry for answering this late, I was traveling and no wi-fi. Yup, some are, others not. In fact, the latter shouldn't get a 404. They should show a sub-term page for that sub-term saying something like: "Sorry, no content matched your criteria.", not a 404. This is a very basic setup, latest WP with Genesis Sample theme, Query Monitor, FacetWP and no complications. The only thing is that all terms were imported (just the terms, no posts or anything) from an .xml file from another clean install. Flushed permalinks, so I don't know.

Comment: @Milo, this is what happens: for the sake of brevity, I mentioned there's a cpt and a taxonomy (just to simplify the code). With one taxonomy, all works well. But (sorry, really) in reality there are seven taxonomies, every one of them for types of locations. So, instead of one 'locations' taxonomy, I have 'admin-locations' for administrative locations, such as country, state, etc, 'natural-locations' for mountain ranges, etc., up to seven types. So when there's more than one location type for the same cpt, 404 everywhere. Even with no imports, just adding a couple of terms with taxonomy empty

Comment: Does each of the taxonomies have a unique slug? You can't share a slug between multiple taxonomies / post types, WordPress determines what to query by the URL pattern, so whatever taxonomy is registered last will override any previous taxonomy with the same slug.

Comment: The only way to share a slug is to resolve all of those requests manually, by determining which taxonomy it comes from *before* the main query is run. Not especially efficient. Every taxonomy would also have to have all terms unique to each taxonomy, or there would never be a way to determine which is meant to be queried.

Comment: Yes, of course we've been careful to not repeat any single term across taxonomies, so when 'ny' gets repeated, one of the terms is 'ny-city' and the other is 'ny-whatever'. But then term pages URL's should be site/houses/ny-city/ and site/houses/ny-whatever/. I saw the trac ticket and John Blackbourn's patch added by Nacin that solves terms across multiple post types. But it doesn't seem to work across taxonomies for one post type. I don't fully understand the mechanics of that resolving requests you mention and its efficiency. Would you care to expand on that? No solution then? Rewrite maybe?

Comment: 2.- I'm thinking a possible efficient trick as per @otto 2011 article "When to (not) use a Custom Taxonomy". Could be fast enough and efficient to have just one taxonomy (unique slug, but that would be around 10,000 terms) with term meta attached to terms and then meta-query? Even I could just add key (indexed) but not necessarilly the value, since the key would be the 'admin', 'natural', matching the seven taxonomies I have now, so seven term meta keys per term. If key exists, yes. If not, discard. Does that make sense? Should this unique taxonomy be non-hierarchical or doesn't matter? Thanks

Comment: A rewrite can't solve it, this is exactly the problem. Not sure how you're imagining term meta would solve this? Resolving manually means hooking into query parsing and checking each taxonomy individually for the requested term until you determine which one it belongs to, then set the correct query vars so the main query will succeed.

Comment: Let's play unique tax 'locations' and 2 term meta for every term: 'admin' and 'natural'. Our slug problem is gone. Then I can query for taxonomy term with 'admin' term meta in it. Basic version would be if 'admin' has value 'yes', that's a list of posts from, say, my original 'ny-city' term with slug site/houses/ny-city/. Is that right or am I totally missing the point? I'm thinking that should be a 'flat' taxonomy (like tags) so posts can belong to more than one term.